# git: 2 developers worked on master branch :(

Tags: git

Well, I didn't follow the best practises and I'm now kind of stuck, not knowning what to do exactly.

I worked on master branch and another developper did the same. He pushed his changes to origin/master. I did not push mine but just did a couple of commits in local. There is no more development beeing done in my working dir now. How can I clean this ?

Is it enough to do a fetch on my side to get the last modif done on origin/master without messing the whole thing up ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to just do a git pull from the origin. It will merge the new stuff into your local branch. You can then push your committed local changes to origin as well. If there are any conflicts git will warn you about this and will flag them so you can resolve them manually. There's no need to worry as this is exactly the stuff that git is made for and excels at.

Comment: You might want to make it clear that the point where you might get conflicts is after the merge, rather than on pushing, since that is often a source of confusion.

Comment: You're right, git will show conflicts on merge. If there's something wrong while pushing, it will simply refuse the push.

Comment: The point was that you should edit your answer to make that unambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

If you run `git fetch origin`, that will update `origin/master` and all the other remote-tracking branches.  (They're essentially like caches of the state of those branches on `origin`.)

Now if you just do `git merge origin/master`, you should be able to do `git push origin master` since now your `master`'s history will include the history of `master` from `origin`.

If you're bothered about preserving a linear history (which many people seem to be), you would do `git rebase origin/master` before pushing.

As (approximate) shortcuts for doing `git fetch origin` and then `git merge origin/master` or `git rebase origin/master`, you can do:

```
 git pull origin master
```

... or:

```
 git pull --rebase origin master
```

... but personally I think it's clearer do the fetch and merge/rebase separately.

Comment: Thx for drawing my attention to the --rebase option for pull. Never used that one

Comment: @mark-longair, I am not familiar with the rebase option neither. Can I only do this because my local changes have already been commited ? What if there were some pending dev in my local working repository ?

Comment: @Luc: git won't let you rebase unless you have a clean working tree, so, yes, you do need to have your work committed first.  Since `git rebase` rewrites the history of your branch, I probably would stick with a plain `git merge origin/master` or `git pull origin master` until you're more confident with git.

Answer (score 1):

Rebase your changes on top the new master, then push

```
git rebase origin/master
git push origin
```

Of course, if there are any merge conflicts, you'l have to resolve them (after resolving `git rebase --continue`, but the tool will tell you how to do that when it happens).

If you prefer, you can merge the branches (it is *still* your branch, even if you ever cloned it from master):

```
git merge origin/master
git push origin
```

You'll have the same merges and possibly the same conflicts, but the history will be subtly different: a rebase 'groups' all your commits at the end of the new master branch, whereas a merge will have them appear interspersed (with chronological log, not topological order) as they happened in time.

Cheers